# TWTRTweetTableViewCell unable to detect links - Fabric TwitterKit

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I made my own UITableViewController and I'm trying to get my TWTRTweetTableViewCell objects to detect links. 
I have an array of TWTRTweet objects that I use to generate my table view cells. This works perfectly but the cells cannot detect URL links.

```
var statuses: [TWTRTweet]!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let status = statuses[indexPath.row]

    let tweetViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TwitterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TWTRTweetTableViewCell

    tweetViewCell.configureWithTweet(status)

    return tweetViewCell
}
```

I even tried setting link colors to red to no avail.

```
TWTRTweetView.appearance().linkTextColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a me setting "include_entities" parameter to false.

The fix was to set it to true in my URLRequestWithMethod request.

Answer (score 0):

use UITextview inside table view cell and setting the textview attribute in storyboard like this:- editable : No, selectable: yes, Detection: select all attributes under this section..

Comment: can't do this. tweetViewCell.configureWithTweet(status) loads a TWTRTweetView object inside the cell.